# java.sql.SQLException: Unable to run insert stmt on object

Tags: android, sqlite, ormlite

I have been trying to insert a record into the database but its not working in Android even though I have done it before. This is the first time I am working with multiple tables in ORMLite.

This is what I am trying to do:
Storing data from XML into a model
Then trying to insert the data from the model.

DataBase used: SQLite
ORM: ORMLite

ActivityClass

```
TbDriverInfoBO tbDriverInfoBO = new TbDriverInfoBO();
Document doc = XMLfunctions.XMLfromString(strResult);
NodeList nodes = doc.getElementsByTagName("root");
Element root = (Element) nodes.item(0);
jabongModel.setLoginId(XMLfunctions.getValue(root, "UserId"));
jabongModel.setPassword(XMLfunctions.getValue(root, "UserPwd"));
jabongModel.setDrsno(XMLfunctions.getValue(root, "DRSNo"));
jabongModel.setBrancode(XMLfunctions.getValue(root, "BranchCode"));
jabongModel.setLoginDate(XMLfunctions.getValue(root, "LoginDate"));
//clsDriverInfo obj = new clsDriverInfo(loginId, pswd, drsno,
/*tbDriverInfoBO.setColUserId(jabongModel.getLoginId());
tbDriverInfoBO.setColPwd(jabongModel.getPassword());
tbDriverInfoBO.setColDrs(jabongModel.getDrsno());
tbDriverInfoBO.setColBranch(jabongModel.getBrancode());*/

tbDriverInfoBO.fillBo(jabongModel);

dbHelperTbDriverInfo.addData(tbDriverInfoBO);
```

BOClass:

```
public class TbDriverInfoBO {

    @DatabaseField(generatedId = true)
    int id;
    @DatabaseField
    String colUserId;
        ...

        // getters and setters

    public TbDriverInfoBO(String colUserId, String colPwd, String colDrs, String colBranch)
    {
        this.colBranch = colBranch;
        this.colDrs = colDrs;
        this.colPwd = colPwd;
        this.colUserId = colUserId;
    }

    public TbDriverInfoBO() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }
    public void fillBo(JabongModel jabongModel)
    {
       this.colBranch = jabongModel.getBrancode();
       this.colDrs = jabongModel.getDrsno();
       this.colPwd = jabongModel.getPassword();
       this.colUserId = jabongModel.getLoginId();
       //this.id = jabongModel.getId();

    }
}



DBHelperClass
public int addData(TbDriverInfoBO tbDriverInfoBO) {
    int i=0;
    RuntimeExceptionDao<TbDriverInfoBO, String> dao = getTbDriverInfoDaO();
    try{
     i = dao.create(tbDriverInfoBO);
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.getStackTrace();// TODO: handle exception
    }
    return i;
}
```

I cannot make out where have I gone wrong. Somebody please help!!!

Here is the stack trace(Log Cat Obtained):

```
01-28 15:43:46.251: D/dalvikvm(368): threadid=1: still suspended after undo (sc=1 dc=1 s=Y)
01-28 15:43:46.251: D/dalvikvm(368): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 8148 objects / 498080 bytes in 72ms
01-28 15:43:49.514: D/dalvikvm(368): threadid=1: still suspended after undo (sc=1 dc=1 s=Y)
01-28 15:43:50.790: D/dalvikvm(368): threadid=1: still suspended after undo (sc=1 dc=1 s=Y)
01-28 15:43:50.900: I/Database(368): sqlite returned: error code = 1, msg = no such table: tbdriverinfobo
01-28 15:43:58.681: D/dalvikvm(368): threadid=1: still suspended after undo (sc=1 dc=1 s=Y)
01-28 15:44:01.956: D/dalvikvm(368): threadid=1: still suspended after undo (sc=1 dc=1 s=Y)
```

Comment: I have added the stack trace. But I am creating DBHelper class for each table. Also before firing this query I am querying on view table but as no records are present in view table I am not getting any records from there. Later I am querying on this TBDriverInfo table.

Comment: Some one please help... Its urgent

Comment: People here are helping you for free while they also have stuff to do, so please just avoid *"It's urgent"* comments. I don't see any exception in your stacktrace. Post the stacktrace of the SQLException.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Looks to me that you are *not* creating the table for `tbdriverinfobo`.

```
sqlite returned: error code = 1, msg = no such table: tbdriverinfobo
```

Can you show your `onCreate()` method in the helper?  Does your application have an existing database and you've added this table afterwards?  Do you need to increment your database version number?

Comment: in onCreate I had to call createIfTableDoesNotExist instead createTable. It works fine for me know. Although I have to call it explicitly before inserting data in all my dbhelper class. I have used it before but never called it explicitly before inserting data. I wonder why such behavior.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error because you created your database and tables 
before new table you want

> tbDriverInfoBO (this is your new table)

and ORMLite library is throwing exception like "Couldn't find table ***tbDriverInfoBO***...." something like this.. So you need to uninstall your mobile app from your phone and then you should write all table class to onCreate method like below code...

```
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase database, ConnectionSource connectionSource) {
    try {
        TableUtils.createTable(connectionSource, Table1.class);
        TableUtils.createTable(connectionSource, Table2.class);
        TableUtils.createTable(connectionSource, Table3.class);
        TableUtils.createTable(connectionSource, Table4.class);
        TableUtils.createTable(connectionSource, Table5.class);//you must add all your table class 
        TableUtils.createTable(connectionSource, TableN.class);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

after adding all table class you can add data to your local tables...

I hope my answer helps someone... happy coding